# DQN cannot converge while the example with the same graph works

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, tensorboard

Here is the problem. I try to rewrite a dpn example of the CartPole-v0. The example converges with less than 2000 episodes, However, my version could not converge.

Therefore I use TensorBoard as the tool to help me figure out the problem. I find that these two codes have the same graph

What's more, I find that the graph of the loss is very different.
[loss of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBBM5.png)
[loss of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afliU.png)

I wonder what's the problem. I will be grateful if anyone could help me with it! Thank you!

P.S. If the codes are needed. I could upload them. Both of them are shorter than 200 lines.

Comment: Please post the code